# Qt/C++ get Json request

Tags: c++, json, qt

I'm new to Qt Framework and I'm trying to get the list of earthquakes from EMSC api. My code looks like this:

```
void MainWindow::getJsonData(QNetworkAccessManager *mNetworkManager) {
    const QUrl json("https://www.seismicportal.eu/fdsnws/event/1/query?limit=100&format=json");
    QNetworkRequest *mNetworkRequest = new QNetworkRequest;
    mNetworkRequest->setUrl(json);
    mNetworkRequest->setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    mNetworkRequest->setRawHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    QNetworkReply *mNetworkReply = mNetworkManager->get(*mNetworkRequest);
    QString replyString = (QString) mNetworkReply->readAll();

    QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(replyString.toUtf8());
    QJsonObject object = document.object();
    QJsonValue type = object["type"].toString();
    QJsonArray featuresArray = object["features"].toArray();

    qDebug() << type;
    qDebug() << featuresArray;
}
```

The problem is that I'm not getting any response from the server.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think the calls you're using are asynchronous calls, and you need to actually set up with a connect() call to get called back when the request completes.

Answer (score 0):

Qt is a library (not a framework) that handles all transactions asynchronously through signals and slots, so don't expect the response to be obtained synchronously.

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>


class Client: public QObject{
public:
    void startRequest(){
        const QUrl json("https://www.seismicportal.eu/fdsnws/event/1/query?limit=100&format=json");
        QNetworkRequest request;
        request.setUrl(json);
        request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.setRawHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        QNetworkReply *reply = mNetworkManager.get(request);
        connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &Client::processRequest);
    }
private:
    void processRequest(){
        QNetworkReply * reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply *>(sender());
        if(!reply) return;

        QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll());
        QJsonObject object = document.object();
        QJsonValue type = object["type"].toString();
        QJsonArray featuresArray = object["features"].toArray();
        qDebug() << type << featuresArray;
        reply->deleteLater();
    }
    QNetworkAccessManager mNetworkManager;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Client client;
    client.startRequest();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
QJsonValue(string, "FeatureCollection") QJsonArray([{"geometry":{"coordinates":[16.23,45.4,-2],"type":"Point"},"id":"20210202_0000178", ...
```

Comment: Thank you for you explanation. I'm just a physicist doing some programming, I'm new to Json. All my experience is numerical computing with fortran and C code. I tried but I'm getting null values. Anyway I will do some research about it, so thanks again. Cannot mark as accepted answer because I don't have enough reputation on SO.

Comment: @EraldGuri 1) please do not victimize yourself as nobody is judging you here and what you indicate is only considered noise, 2) it is not necessary to have a reputation to mark an answer as correct so please read [ask] and check the [tour]

Answer (score -1):

Here's some of my code:

```
QNetworkRequest req (QUrl(QString::fromStdString(url)));
req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::KnownHeaders::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
if (authHeader.length() > 0) {
    req.setRawHeader(QByteArray("Authorization"), QByteArray::fromStdString(authHeader));
}
QByteArray bodyArray;

if (body.length() > 0) {
    bodyArray.append(QString::fromStdString(body).toUtf8());
}

QNetworkReply * reply = method(req, bodyArray);

QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [=]{
.... });
```

Comment: Just dropping code without any explanation does not make a good answer. Also, what is `method`?

Comment: @JarMan I didn't want to cut + paste 1000 lines of code. The important part is seeing that you have to set up the connect statement. This goes with the comment I wrote earlier about async.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understood what I missed out.

Comment: @JosephLarson You misunderstood my comment. I did not say you needed more code, but more explanation. Answers on SO are not just intended for the original poster, but also for anybody else who may have a similar question. If someone came across this post and looked at your answer, they're not likely to understand it. And referring back to a comment somewhere is not good either because comments can be deleted separately from your answer.